# How to setup 301 redirects for multiple query string URLs?

Tags: redirect, urls, nginx

I have multiple URLs that follow the same pattern like this:

`https://example.com/hashtag?tag=[$string]`

Is there a way to perform a 301 redirect to the following URL instead?

`https://example.com/tags/[$string]`

If I use this plugin, [Safe Redirect Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/), is there a way to set that up?

My Server:

- VPS CenterOS
- NGINX

Comment: Has your question been solved? If so, please click the green checkbox next to my answer so it let's the community know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From doing some research, I'd recommend trying out this plugin: [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/installation/). This plugin allows you to manage 301 redirections.

I played around with the settings and they allows regular expressions which could do the following:

`http://some.site/hashtag?tag=some-tag/` to `http://some.site/tags/some-tag/`

They provide documentation on how to set it up which can be found [here](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/). This is what I've done when creating the rule, try this:

[image]

- **Source URL**: `/hashtag?tag=(.*)/`
- **Target URL**: `/tags/(.*)`

I was testing this out on a local copy of WordPress and I don't have anything right now that gives me those URL structures. Let me know if that works for you on your end. Again, you can play around with the regular expressions to get it right.

Comment: Thank Ethan Jinks O'Sullivan, this is a perfect solution ;)

Comment: @NvD Great, glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite right.

1. Source URL: /hashtag?tag=(.*)/
2. Target URL: /tags/$1

The Dollar symbol says match that first value ($2 would be the second, which isn't required here)